# How to determine whether the template type is a class with function name "pack" or not

Tags: c++, templates, types

```
template <class T>
void packarg(char* &szBuff,  T t)
{
    if (????)
    {
        t.pack(szBuff, 10240, &iTmpSize);
    }
    else
    {   
        memcpy(szBuff, &t, sizeof(T));
    }
}
```

I Have Code like this, if the type T has interface pack then use pack interface, if not, then memcpy it.
So, the question is how I determine whether Type T has Interface "pack" or not.
PS: I'm using C++11.

Comment: Check out `std::enable_if` and `std::void_t`

Comment: I'd recommend giving [this article](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/checking_expression_validity_in_place.html) a read. In addition, C++20 simplifies this further in that `requires(char* &szBuff, T t, int iTmpSize) { t.pack(szBuff, 10240, &iTmpSize); }` is an expression that evaluates to true or false depending whether the call is valid and can then be used on the fly or put into a named concept.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is write a traits template to determine whether or not a type has that member and that member is callable with a certain set of parameter types.

```
#include <type_traits>

// a SFINAE helper
template<typename T, typename...>
using first_t = T;

// by default, the trait is false
template<typename...>
struct has_pack_member : std::false_type {};

// if T has a member pack() callable with argument types Args..., the trait is true
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct has_pack_member<
    first_t<
        T,
        decltype( std::declval<T>().pack( std::declval<Args>()... ) )
    >,
    Args...
> :
    std::true_type
{};
```

This trait can be used like such in C++17:

```
if constexpr ( has_pack_member<T, /*argument types*/>::value ) {
    t.pack( /*arguments*/ );
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Before C++17, you need to implement the `if` and `else` branches in two separate function templates with the same name, and conditionally enable one or the other based on whether the trait is true or false.

Comment: On certain compilers, this might break if the function has zero arguments. In that case you need to break out the zero-argument case separately.

Comment: Until [CWG 1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558) (a C++14 defect), `template<typename T, typename...>
using first_t = T` doesn't SFINAE correctly as [`std:void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)

Comment: +1, didn't know about this. I don't know how you'd write this in C++11 with variadic arguments then, but you can just hard code the argument types I suppose.

Comment: "Direct" aliasing is the issue, `template<typename T, typename...>
struct first { usint type = T;}; template<typename T, typename...Ts> using first_t = typename first<T, Ts...>::type;` is ok.